# Kendo Grid: list all colum headers in a dropdown to see it instantly without scrolling horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and got lots of columns for looking a specific column i have to scroll a lot horizontally and deep down my eyes to see where is that column, can we a column search text box so when i enter column name it should scroll me there to that column or can we list all columns(names) in a dropdown above my kendo grid so by selecting that i can see that column highlighted or selected.
I tried finding it a lot but could not found, i have bought kendo grid.
Help me out.!!
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   ...
});

// Generate column list
var gridColumns = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").options.columns,
    htmlOptions = "";

for (var i = 0; i < gridColumns.length; i++) {
    htmlOptions+= "<option value='" + i + "'>" + gridColumns[i].title + "</option>";
}

$("#column-list")
    .append(htmlOptions)
    .on("change", function() {
        // get the grid
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        // Find the TH element inside the grid's THEAD based on chosen index
        var chosenColumn = $(grid.element).find("thead th:eq(" + $(this).val() + ")");

        // Scroll to the column by its offsetLeft property
        scroll(chosenColumn[0].offsetLeft);
    });

// Scroll function
var scroll = function(pos) {
    $(".k-grid-content")[0].scrollLeft = pos;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="column-list"></select>
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OKaCi). The snippet is self-explained in its own comments. If they aren't enough to you to understand, please tell me.

Reference:

- [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft)